ByBit API: How to get info on all positions?
I cannot use the get_positions() function to get information about all positions. I can only get information about each individual position. How can I get info of all existing positions?
session = HTTP(testnet=False, api_key=API_KEY, api_secret=API_SECRET)
session.get_positions(category="linear")

Error: File "I:\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pybit\_http_manager.py", line 379, in _submit_request
 raise InvalidRequestError(
pybit.exceptions.InvalidRequestError: Missing some parameters that must be filled in, symbol or settleCoin (ErrCode: 10001) (ErrTime: 13:51:04).
Request → GET https://api.bybit.com/v5/position/list: category=linear.

It works if I get the information of each existing position. Ex: session.get_positions(category="linear", symbol="BTCUSDT")

The documentation mentions "For linear, either symbol or settleCoin is required", as also stated in your error message.

Good that you solved it. If you want you can answer your own question here, it may be useful for other people.

Thank you @Marijn. I solved my issue.  I used this: session.get_positions(category="linear", settleCoin='USDT').

@Marijn. This is the first time I have used stack overflow. There are many things I don't know. Thanks for helping me, bro.

https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/v5/position
You have to specify the symbolr OR the settleCoin (USDT, USDC) :)

Welcome to StackOverflow, can you also include a code snippet to show your answer?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
